# Как автоматически загружать данные с базы данных через php

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня назрел очень важный вопрос. Как мне автоматически загружать данные с MySQL с помощью PHP при их обновлении как в Firebase?

Comment: Обычно загружают НА сервер, с сервера и/или из базы данных скачивают/считывают/получают данные. Куда вы хотите их передавать из БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Каким образом происходит обновление данных в вашей БД?
- Куда вы хотите передавать данные?

**Предварительно в условиях дефицита исходных данных видится 2 варианта реализации:**

1. Запускать через CRON некий скрипт, который будет: или тупо отправлять данные, не смотря ни на что, или  будет выполнять некую проверку и по ее результатам отправлять или нет данные. Варианты проверок могут быть разные - все зависит от ваших данных и частоты транзакций по внесению изменений в БД.

*Самая простая проверка - добавить в БД два доп. столбца, в один записывается в формате UNIXTIME время поступления данных (INSERT и/или UPDATE), во втором - время отправки (куда вы там будете слать?), сравниваем времена и понимаем, что слать, а что нет.*

*Если команда UPDATE не будет использоваться, а будет только INSERT, то можно ограничиться только одним дополнительным столбцом: 0 - не отправляли, 1 - отправляли.*

2. Если данные в БД меняются с использованием скрипта/скриптов, то добавить в него/в них функционал отправки нужных данных в нужное место. Так даже корректнее будет - не будет лишних процессов запускаться по команде планировщика.